# Save multiple html-pages with jspdf to single pdf

Tags: javascript, html, jspdf, html2canvas

Currently I have a page where user can click-together a report and save this to a pdf with the following code:

```
document.getElementById('report').onclick = function () {
    // Default export is a4 paper, portrait, using milimeters for units
    html2canvas(document.body, {
        onrendered: function (canvas) {
            var img = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
            var doc = new jsPDF();
            doc.addImage(img, 'JPEG', 0, 0);
            doc.save('test.pdf');
        }
    });
}
```

Is it possible that we can do this multiple times and add all pages to one pdf? Finally when the user clicks another button I want to download the pdf with all the added pages.

Comment: yes you can use doc.addPage for add mutliple pages.

Comment: What if the page gets reloaded inbetween. Can I buffer the current pdf somehow?

Comment: I think you can't

Comment: Could I send the file back to my node server and add them all together there and just send it back when the user presses download?